# JS Passing front end input data to function params

Tags: solidity, javascript, frontend

In a nutshell: I am trying to get data from the front end (string input) to flow to my backend function parameters. See code below

```
export default function foo() {
  const boilerplate


  const { runContractFunction: createfunction } = useWeb3Contract({
    abi: abi,
    contractAddress: functionAddress,
    functionName: "createafunction",
    params: { "input 1": "input 2" }, //these parameters should come from the input boxes (document.getElementById("input 1 and 2").value, etc.)
    msgValue: {},
  });


  useEffect(() => {
    if (isWeb3Enabled) {
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>Input 1</div>
        <input id="input 1"></input>
        <div>Input 2</div>
        <input id="input 2"></input>
        <div>
          <button onClick= *** The onclick should pass the strings from input 1 and input 2 to the params of create a function above);
            }}
          >
            Push button
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Apologies for the newbie question however I am new to both Solidity and JavaScript (as you can tell). Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Thank you for reading :)

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the Values of the input field in State Variable & also

While Passing Params in useWeb3Contract , you have to assign it to the params name in the contract..
eg. if createfunction accepts two string params named  Test and Test2 .. then you can pass as params: { Test: "input 1", Test2:  "input 2" }

Update Code

```
export default function foo() {
  const [input1,setInput1]= useState("");
  const [input2,setInput2]= useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isWeb3Enabled) {
    }
  }, []);

  const { runContractFunction: createfunction } = useWeb3Contract({
    abi: abi,
    contractAddress: functionAddress,
    functionName: "createafunction",
    // Test and Test2 are the params name in the contract.. modify 
    //accordingly
    params: { Test: input1, Test2:  input2 }, 
    msgValue: {},
  });

  async function Update = ()=> {
   const response = await createFunction();
   console.log(response)
  } 

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>Input 1</div>
        <input id="input 1" onChange= {(e}=> setInput1(e.target.value)}></input>
        <div>Input 2</div>
        <input id="input 2" onChange= {(e}=> setInput2(e.target.value)}></input>
        <div>
          <button onClick={ Update}
          >
            Push button
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response and I am going to work at it right away. One thing that caught my eye is that the Update function throws errors. Could it be that the update function should be this:   

async function Update() {
    const response = await createThread();
    console.log(response);
  }